# Remove item from a list, which (of the 2) methods is better?

Tags: java, iterator

I have a `List`, and I have to delete one item from the list when I find it. I am using the code below to do that:

```
Iterator<MyClass> iter = flist.iterator();              
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Long deletedFiId = iter.next().getId(); 
    if (deletedFiId.equals(fiId)) { 
         iter.remove();
         break;
     }
}
```

One of my co-workers suggested I should hold the object to be removed and remove it once we get out of the `for` loop, like this:

```
MyClass deletedFiId = null;
for (MyClass dto: flist) {
  if (dto.getId().equals(fiId)) {
    deletedFiId = dto;
    break;
  }
if (deletedFiId != null)
  fiList.remove(deletedFiId);
```

Which one of the above is a good-to-have in the code?

Comment: Calling `iter.next()` on an `Iterator<Object>` should return an `Object`. How do you call `.getId()` on an `Object`?

Comment: Don't care if there's a third, better way?

Comment: @200_success: I did change, the then confusing datatype.

Comment: @retailcoder: I would definitely like to know a better way, other than the above two. Is there any?

Comment: I don't know really, it's just the way you've worded your question looks like it's narrowing the kind of code reviews you'll get to "Go with A because xyz" or "Go with B because xyz". It's not forbidden, but it's not the best way to ask for a review and get the best out of the reviewers imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two methods are functionally identical.
The first method is faster to execute.
The first method is clearer for someone who doesn't know the code.

Unless there's an "else" you need (that is, logic to execute if the item can't be found), I can't think of a reason to prefer the second approach.

First approach wins.

Answer (score 2):

1. The first one uses `equals` while the second one uses `==` for the comparison. [They are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur/).
2. In the second snippet `fi` could be renamed to `deletableItem` or something more meaningful and easier to read. ([How to abbreviate variable names](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/72595/36726) on Programmers.SE.)
3. `iter.remove` in first snippet uses `equals` of your ID class while the second snippet uses `fiList.remove` which uses `fi.equals()` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)) It *might* produce different result lists depending on the implementation of your `equals` method.

Comment: I changed the second snippet to use .equals() and have same name as the first snippet.